# RxJava2, repeatUntil and whileDo

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm not sure I understand repeatUntil. I wanted to have something like this:

1. Create observable from just
2. Check condition and if it's true run all downstreams, otherwise just complete
3. Repeat the second point

Here is my test Observable, which runs into ***IndexOutOfBoundsException***

```
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(values)
            .repeatUntil(() -> values.isEmpty())
            .map(integers -> values.remove(0));
    observable.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer), 
          throwable -> System.out.println(throwable));
```

It seems to me, repeatUntil will be executed first time at the end.

Am I wrong? And if I'm right, how to check condition at the begining?

I also saw, that there was whileDo-operator in rxJava1. Where is it now?

**UPD**

I could somehow solve the problem by using takeWhile before repeatUntil, but maybe there is a better solution?

```
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    /*
    values.add(0);
    values.add(1);
    values.add(2);
    values.add(3);
    values.add(4);
    */

    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(values)
            .takeWhile(integers -> values.size() > 0)
            .map(integers -> values.remove(0))
            .repeatUntil(() -> values.isEmpty());
    observable.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("Test " + integer), 
             throwable -> System.out.println(throwable), 
             () -> System.out.println("Completed"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RepeatUntil calls the function when its upstream completes, which is after it has signalled the empty `ArrayList`, thus you get the exception because the `remove` will find that empty `ArrayList`.

The `whileDo` operator lives in the [RxJava 2 Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#whiledo) project.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

StatementFlowable.whileDo(
    Observable.just(values),
    () -> values.isEmpty()
)
.map(integers -> values.remove(0))
.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer), 
      throwable -> System.out.println(throwable))
;
```

Comment: And what happend to whileDo operator from the rxJava1? Or was it always in your library?

Comment: The `whileDo` was in the [RxJavaComputationExpressions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaComputationExpressions) library almost 4 years by now. The release process on that library was not properly setup and it was much easier to simply do the upgrade to v2 in my own repository that includes other such older addon library content.

Comment: If you want to go with standard operators, the updated example of yours is the way to go.

Comment: i was just wondering to read this "RxJava 1․x doWhile repeat repeatWhen whileDo" from the official docu http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/repeat.html It seems to me, whileDo existed once as standard operator

Comment: Ok. Another quote from the official docu "In RxJava, whileDo is not part of the standard set of operators, but is part of the optional rxjava-computation-expressions package. whileDo checks a condition before each repetition of the source sequence, and only repeats it if that condition is true."

Comment: Originally, I ported `whileDo` from Rx.NET in 2013 into RxJava 0.x, but later on, the project decided to move many operators into external projects.

Comment: ok, I see. I'm just starting with RxJava. Everyday there is something new :)